# Finding two minimum values out of four?

Tags: c, algorithm

So, I have four integers and I need to find out the lowest two out of those four. What would be the most efficient way of doing so in C (or any other language)?

**Edit:** I need a fixed implementation, for the sake of efficiency as this is a very critical operation that is going to be performed thousands of times.

Comment: Not sure about this, so I won't post it as an answer, but a "brute force" method of scanning the list for the lowest value twice, eliminating the element selected in the first pass on the second pass, would guarantee no more than 5 comparisons...

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/12215020/705048 will be hard to beat for efficiency. But if you use it, make sure you comment it thoroughly for the sake of your colleagues!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an efficient implementation using [sorting networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network):

```
inline void Sort2(int *p0, int *p1)
{
    if (*p0 > *p1)
    {
        const int temp = *p0;
        *p0 = *p1;
        *p1 = temp;
    }
}

inline void Sort4(int *p0, int *p1, int *p2, int *p3)
{
    Sort2(p0, p1);
    Sort2(p2, p3);
    Sort2(p0, p2);  
    Sort2(p1, p3);  
    Sort2(p1, p2);  
}
```

This takes only 5 compares and up to 5 swaps. You can just ignore the results for p2, p3.

Note that for a performance-critical application `Sort2` can be implemented without branches in one or two instructions on some architectures.

Comment: Note that my answer is as efficient in the worst case and more efficient in the best case, in terms of the number of comparisons.

Comment: @Hbcdev: unfortunately your solution has a lot of branches, whereas the above solution can be implemented without branches. The number of compares and swaps may be similar, but branches are very expensive when they are mispredicted.

Comment: @PaulR Ah, OK. Can you explain why the branches in my answer are more of a problem than yours? Does X86 have a 'min' instruction? Or is it that my branches are nested so the problem is worse?

Comment: @Hbcdev: OK - as noted in my answer above, the compare and swap operation in `Sort2` can be implemented as a short branchless instruction sequence in many architectures (including x86) - this results in a completely branch-free implementation. As you probably are aware, branch misprediction can be very costly in superscalar CPUs.

Comment: [another answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12216412/849891) gives a comparison sequence where 3 to 4 comparisons are enough, and can also be encoded in branch-free manner (with ternary operator).

Comment: @Will Ness: yes, there is some redundancy in my solution because it is somewhat general purpose in that it does a complete sort, whereas only the first two elements are actually needed and the remaining three need not be sorted. You could prune the above sorting network to give just the first two elements and thereby reduce the number of compares, but then it would be less generally useful.

Answer (score 3):

Just write a loop and keep track of the lowes 2 values ?
Should be at max O(2N) which is i think the best achievable complexity.

Comment: no, [another answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12216412/849891) makes only 3 comparisons in 25% of cases or so.

Comment: yes, yes, writing all needed comparisons under each other is indeed much faster

Comment: it's not about how to write them, but finding a specific order of comparisons.

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way? Trying to avoid any extra steps, I got this (in pseudo-code). This will avoid any unnecessary comparisons that you'll get with other more general solutions (specifically ones that don't advantage of the transitive nature of comparison operations).

Bear in mind that this is only thinking about efficiency, not at all aiming for beautiful code.

```
if a<=b:
  if b<=c:
    # c too big, which of b and d is smaller?
    if b<=d:
      return (a,b)
    else:
      return (a,d)
  else if b<=d:
    # a and c both < b, and b < d
    return (a,c)
  else:
    # b is > a, c and d. Down to just those three.
    if a<=c:
      if c<=d:
        # a < c < d
        return (a,c)
      else:
        # a and d both < c
        return (a,d)
    else if d<=a:
      # Both c and d < a
      return (c,d)
    else:
      # c < a < d
      return (a,c)
else:
  # b < a
  if a<=c:
    # c too big, which of a and d is smaller?
    if a<=d:
      return (a,b)
    else:
      return (b,d)
  else if a<=d:
    # b and c both < a, and a < d
    return (b,c)
  else:
    # a is > b, c and d. Down to just those three.
    if b<=c:
      if c<=d:
        # b < c < d
        return (b,c)
      else:
        # b and d both < c
        return (b,d)
    else if d<=b:
      # Both c and d < b
      return (c,d)
    else:
      # c < b < d
      return (b,c)
```

I think this has a worst case of 5 comparisons and a best case of 3 (obviously there's no way of doing it in less than 3 comparison).

Answer (score 3):

You can get away with exactly 4 comparisons and maximally 4 swaps.

```
inline void swap(int* i, int* j) {
  static int buffer;
  buffer = *j;
  *j = *i;
  *i = buffer;
}

inline void sort2(int* a, int* s) {
  if (*s < a[1])
    swap(s,a+1);
  if (*s < a[0]) // it is NOT sufficient to say "else if" here
    swap(s,a);
}

inline void sort4(int* a) {
  sort2(a,a+2);
  sort2(a,a+3);
}
```

The result will be sitting the the first to cells, but note that these cells are not necessarily sorted! They're just the smallest elements.

Comment: this is not optimal. [another answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12216412/849891) makes only 3 comparisons in 25% of cases or so.

Answer (score 2):

I would make an array out of them, sort and take the first two values.

Comment: or the last two depending on how you sorted ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish it with at most 4 comparisons:

- compare the first pair of numbers and let the smaller be `a1` and the larger be `a2`
- compare the second pair of numbers and let the smaller be `a3` and the larger be `a4`
- if a1 >= a4 return (a3, a4)
- (now we know that that a1 < a4)
- if a3 >= a2 return (a1, a2)
- (now we also know that a3 < a2)
- return (a1, a3)

To see that this is true, you can check all the combinations of possible returns:

(a1, a2) (a1, a3) (a1, a4)

(a2, a3) (a2, a4)

(a3, a4)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can sort the array and pick the first two elements.